# reversing the "Measured voltage" in Simulink

Tags: simulink, simscape, simpowersystems

Within Simulink, we can use the "Measure voltage" to get a numerical representation (Simulink Signal) of the voltage and use it for mathematical operations. Does there exist a way to take a numerical representation (Simulink Signal)  and convert it into a voltage signal that I can send through an inverter or rectifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Simscape/SimPowerSystems. The answer is yes, use the [Controlled Voltage Source](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/ref/controlledvoltagesource.html) block from the Electrical Sources library of Simscape or the equivalent [Controlled Voltage Source](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/controlledvoltagesource.html) block from the Electrical Sources library of SimPowerSystems (if you use the old generation library of SimPowerSystems, the new one is Simscape-based so you can use the Simscape blocks).